# Updated Workflow

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I have updated a workflow with items I have changed like who to email, and email body....but when I published it only works for documents that are newly uploaded into the library. It does not become active for the documents that are already uploaded into the library. This is what the library is for: Someone uploads a doc into the library, another person views, clicks the link to approve the doc, and once they click the approve or disapproved button it should email the people on the list. It was not working for the pass docs in the library but I fixed it but I need it to work for the pass doc in the library.

Comment: Just for clarification ---- you want all the existing docs to have the approval process started on them?  How many docs are in the library?

Comment: Yes, Not too many documents, maybe 20. The docs are running the old Workflow, I want them to run  the new workflow. I cnnot delete and resubmitt the docs because they are uploaded from a different place.

Answer (score 1):

Workflows are "point in time". What I mean is if workflows are running under a previous version, they continue to operate under that version until complete. If you make changes to the workflow, newly created items work properly. If you need previous items to run under the new workflow, the workflows running on the existing items need to be stopped, and then reinitiated.

Comment: Stop the workflow on each item, then restart it.